# Can this inbound & outbound bandwidth of my server cause issues?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server

I have a social app where users do the usual stuff of other social apps; upload multiple text and photo posts every hour, like & comment (a notification is created for each action), view custom/native ads, block users (and their content) etc.

The app runs on a `Parse Server` of version `2.8.4`. For those who don't know, `Parse Server` uses `Node.js`, `express` and `MongoDB`. I have 1 server for the app and another one for the db, both hosted on DigitalOcean.

Here are their specs:

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz x4
8 GB of RAM
SSD
Ubuntu 16.04
```

Normally, we have about 100-150 simultaneous users every day that create about 500 posts a day, 2000 comments, 2000 likes and each of them usually stays in for about 40 minutes. but today we reached 600 and the app literally froze! I saw the charts provided by DigitalOcean and every metric (cpu, ram etc) was normal, 40-50 percent max. The inbound & outbound bandwidth on the other hand peaked!

As you can see in the image below, every day we hit about 6 Mbps of inbound and 2.5 Mbps of outbound. Today, we hit over 10 Mbps of inbound and 15 Mbps of outbound!

[image]

> The app runs with `pm2` on a single CPU. During the incident, we tried
> using all 4 of them but nothing seemed to improve... it still froze.
> We also don't cache anything at the moment (we will though real soon). The db is indexed, but other than that not much have been done for improvement. All photos are stored in an `S3` of DigitalOcean.

The question is, considering that every other metric was of normal highs, and that the db is fairly-well structured, do you think that this bandwidth spike could cause a total freeze on the server, or it wouldn't affect that at all? Could it be that the server we're using isn’t good enough to support the app?

Also, how many users do you think our infrastructure should support? I know it depends on many factors, but based on what I described is it normal not to be able to handle 600 users?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the app froze... If your server showed normal load in metrics I doubt it's because the server itself has an issue. It seems like your bandwidth was throttling peoples' connections. Perhaps the inbound and outbound connection speeds are lower than  the 10 and 15Mbps you hit?

If that's the case, try getting (paying for) a higher speed connection. Your server would be able to handle many gigabits/sec before the hardware can't keep up, and your server software didn't come even close to capacity. *But* you can't process data that hasn't been transferred; and that created a bottleneck for everything else.